# While fetching all records from the DB, assign to a ViewModel attribute average rating for each record

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Basically, I'm fetching all records from a certain table, selecting into a new VM class. I've come up with this code for calculating Average Rating, however, the code produces correct average (grouped by fetched objects' Id). The problem is, these averages/values are in the form of `IQueryable` whereas I need them to be assigned each to the corresponding record.

```
return _ctx.LodgingDbSet.Select(x => new LodgingVM
{
    LodgingId = x.Id,
    LodgingName = x.Name,
    LodgingAddress = x.Address,
    LodgingEmail = x.Email,
    LodgingPhone = x.Phone,

    LodgingAverageRating = _ctx.RatingDbSet.GroupBy(
           g => g.Reservation.Unit.LodgingId, r => r.Score)
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    LodgingId = g.Key,
                    Score = g.Average()
                }).Select(g => g.Score),

            LodgingImage = x.Image,
            LodgingImageThumb = x.ImageThumb

        }).OrderBy(o => o.LodgingName).ToList();
```

The VM attribute `LodgingAverageRating` should only contain average value for that particular Lodging. Currently, the code I have for calculating average returns all average values that get calculated.

Comment: `_ctx.RatingDbSet.Where(r => r.Reservation.Unit.LodgingId == x.Id).GroupBy(.....` try this..

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes, since there's correct filtering involved, now I'm getting a single result, as desired, and can use FirstOrDefault() at the end.
Please create an answer with this proposal so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [GroupJoin](https://www.dotnetperls.com/groupjoin) to Join and group the result and then use `Average` extension method?

```
return _ctx.LodgingDbSet.GroupJoin(_ctx.RatingDbSet,
                            lodging => lodging.Id,
                            rating => rating.Reservation.Unit.LodgingId,
                            (l, groupedRating) => new LodgingVM
                            {
                                LodgingId = x.Id,
                                LodgingName = x.Name,
                                LodgingAddress = x.Address,
                                LodgingEmail = x.Email,
                                LodgingPhone = x.Phone,
                                LodgingAverageRating = groupedRating.Average(x => x.Score),
                                LodgingImage = x.Image,
                                LodgingImageThumb = x.ImageThumb
                            }).OrderBy(o => o.LodgingName).ToList();
```